# Connecting 5.1 speaker set to Pc

Tags: audio, surround-sound

I bought a 5.1 speaker set: yamaha nsp40 (http://m.asia.yamaha.com/en/products/audio-visual/speaker-systems/speaker-packages/ns-p40_w/)

My pc soundcard supports surround and has all the necessary 3.5mm outputs, but the speakers all have bare wire inputs (negative/positive) except for the big subwoofer which has RCA.

Whats the best way to connect this to my pc? Do i need an amplifier? My soundcard is Realtek ALC892. Ive searched the internet but I couldnt find a clear answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [manual](http://download.yamaha.com/api/asset/file/?language=en&site=asia.yamaha.com&asset_id=54613), yes, you need an amplifier. Other than the subwoofer, none of the speakers are powered. Off hand, I think you may also need to connect the PC to the amplifier over something like toslink,spdif or HDMI out (unless you have inputs for all 5+1 channels on the amp, and use a regular 5.1/7.1 sound card and *many* 3.5mm interconnects), but I'm not entirely sure there - You may want to make sure you can output from your PC to your amplifier with the desired number of channels when you get it.

[image]